# C# to find data from CSV in a file

Tags: c#, csv

I have a one line of values as a CSV file,
I need to find if each one of them exist in a nother file (XML for that matter).

I have read the CSV data, split the values and the search code works BUT output a false results (“find” values that does not exist)
I’ll appetite any help.
Thanks Shabi

My code

```
string csvFile = @"Afile.csv";
string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(csvFile);
string namesValues = lines[0];

List<string> allValidNamesValues = namesValues.Split(',').ToList();

bool result = false;

string DeviceName = Phone.Tag("Name").Value();

if (allValidNamesValues.Any(vn => DeviceName.IndexOf(vn, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) != -1))
{
    Info = string.Format("The Device is supported");
    return true;
}

return result;
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the line and value that is problematic? It could be as simple as reversing `vn.IndexOf(DeviceName)`, for example. Note: in the general case, `.Split(',')` is **not** a correct implementation of CSV processing, as CSV is actually more complex than that. You might get away with it in some cases, though.

Comment: Note also: you're only looking in the first line of the file (but all "columns", where "columns" is a loose and unreliable interpretation of "split by comma"); is that intentional?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you really want something like that:

1. Test 1st *column* of the CSV
2. Skip CSV caption (1st line)

The implemantation

```
 string DeviceName = Phone.Tag("Name").Value();
 string csvFile = @"Afile.csv";

 var result = File
   .ReadLines(csvFile) // You have no need to read all the lines 
   .Skip(1) // skip title, comment out this if CSV has no caption
   .Select(line => line.Split(',')) // providing that CSV doen't have quotations
   .Select(items => items[0]) // providing that 1ast column contains names
   .Any(name => String.Equals(name, DeviceName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the primary problem here is that you're only processing the first line of the file (`lines[0]`). You can either use a nested loop to process all the lines, or `SelectMany` (LINQ). For example (and using `ReadLines` to avoid the need to buffer all the data at once):

```
static readonly char[] comma = { ',' };
...
if(File.ReadLines(csvFile).SelectMany(x => x.Split(comma)).Any(
        vn => DeviceName.IndexOf(vn, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) != -1))
{
    // whatever
}
```

Note that I'm not convinced the string test is correct (to me it would seem more obvious to have `vn.IndexOf(DeviceName, ...)`, but: hard to check that without examples.

To do a more *correct* parsing of CSV is more complex; you should consider libraries like [LumenWorksCsvReader](https://www.nuget.org/packages/LumenWorksCsvReader/)

Comment: I'm processing only the first line because there is only one line of data.

Comment: @ShabiLevanda see, that's the kind of detail you should include in the question... any update on sample data we can look, that you think should pass/fail but doesn't?